# how to loop through in rmakdown with latex?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pdflatex

I want to combine rmarkdown and latex and loop through a dataset column. Is there any way to work on code below

````
```{r}

for (i in 1:10){
  
\begin{itemize}

\item i

\end{itemize}

}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `pgffor` package to create the loop:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document: 
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
- \usepackage{pgffor}
---

\begin{itemize}
\foreach \x in {1,...,10}{
  \item \x
}
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Thanq. ```\begin{itemize}
\foreach \x in {1,...,nrow(df)}{
  \item df[\x,]
}
\end{itemize}``` is this way through loop column

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
dfex <- data.frame(x=letters[1:10], y=LETTERS[1:10])

cat("\\begin{itemize}")
for(i in 1:nrow(dfex)){
  cat(paste("\\item", dfex[i,1]))  
}
cat("\\end{itemize}")
```
````

Important to note: `results='asis'` and `cat` makes sure it is generated as a clean latex output rather than R output. Need double `\\` to explicitly state that it is backslash we want rather than some special character e.g. `\i`.

Example without the need for `result='asis'` using (`knitr::asis_output`)

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
latexItemize <- function(items){
  knitr::asis_output(paste0(
    "\\begin{itemize}",
    paste("\\item", items, collapse=" "),
    "\\end{itemize}"
  ))

}
```


```{r, echo=FALSE}
latexItemize(dfex[,2])
```
````