# How to display dataframe column rows as different points in latex rmarkdown pdf?

Tags: r, r-markdown, pdflatex

```
df column description

description
-----------
Whatever your header text looks like
Whatever header text looks like
Whatever your header text looks 
Whatever your header text like
Whatever your text looks like
```

I want to loop through a df column description and display as pointwise from r-markdown

````
\begin{itemize}
```{r echo=FALSE,results='asis'}


df<-readxl::read_excel(PATh,sheet = 'sheet1')

for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  dummy <- paste0("\\item ",df$description[i])

}
```

`r dummy` 

\end{itemize}
````

i want all rows of column to be shown pointwise. only last one is showing

Comment: Did my answer for your previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/67620998/7162131) not work?

Comment: @henrik_ibsen no it didn't work. In chunk it's working but it's showing with latex functions everything. It is not able to generate pdf. i'm getting ```! LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.```

Comment: You already have the same question here [how to loop through in rmakdown with latex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67497471/how-to-loop-through-in-rmakdown-with-latex). Edit it to improve it, instead of reposting

Answer (score 0):

The loop is rewriting the variable `dummy` each iteration. Consequently, only the final row will be stored. Something like this should work:

```
#define the dummy variable ahead of the loop 
dummy <- character(nrow(df))

#Index the dummy variable to not overwrite it
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  dummy[i] <- paste0("\\item ",df$description[i])

}
```

You would also (probably) need to collapse `dummy` into a single string

```
`r paste(dummy, collapse=" ")`
```